# How can I access Checkboxes in a dynamically created tr using Jquery (Not delegation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a table in which a tr can by dynamically added. The tr contains checkboxes that signify whether a team member has a certain role - this is defined by having a utilisation greater than 0 for that role. The roles and utilisation are set in a dialog box.The following method is called for each different role type when the dialog box values are saved against the team member.

```
if (teamMember.designerUtil > 0) {
  $('tr', '#my-table').eq(tableRow).find("#designerCheck").prop("checked",true);
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is have the checkbox on the tr for the team member that has a role set in the modal check when they have been given the role. The code above works only for the tr that was created when the page loads, NOT for any created dynamically. I have read about event delegation but I don't think there is an event to attach. I just want to check the checkbox using Jquery, not initiate an event.

[Image showing dialog box and table with checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOZkh.png)

Comment: I think the problem is in the order of execution. Are you sure, that you have table rows created in the moment, when you run the posted script? Can you provide more complex example?

Comment: Have you tried using the same code after the new checkboxes are created?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also note that ID's can't be repeated in a page, they are unique by definition

Comment: It is not a problem with the order of execution, the row is added and the row has a button that opens the dialog box. Then on closing the dialog the roles that have been selected should be conveyed through the checkboxes. If I wanted to fire an event from the click of the checkbox I could use delegation but I cannot check it using javascript/jquery, which is what I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If by "dynamically added" you mean created by javascript when the page loads you should be able to execute your code using the document ready function:

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

If by "dynamically added" you mean created by an ajax call you should be able to use ajaxComplted to get the behavior you're looking for.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/

Comment: By dynamically added I mean after the page has loaded, by clicking a button where using javascript/jquery I append a row to the table,

Comment: Are you calling the tr code at the end of the code called by the button press?  Also, have you looked at the html using something like the inspector tool in firefox (tools->web developer->debugger->(inspector button in the lower left corner).  The generated html might be slightly different that what you think and the xpath query might not be exactly correct.